# automapper map class with generic list to same class with a different generic

Tags: c#, generics, automapper

I have this class:

```
public class PagedListResult<T>
{
    public int RecordCount {get; set;}
    public int PageNumber {get; set;}
    public int PageSize {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<T> Records {get; set;}
}
```

now basically I want to be able to create mapper that would map my `EF` entity to my `Dto` model, example:

```
public class UserEntity
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
public class UserDto
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

in my `BLL` class:

```
//other code
PagedListResult<UserEntity> result = _repo.GetUsers();
var pagedListOfDtos = Mapper.Map<PagedListResult<UserDto>>(result);
return pagedListOfDtos;
//other code
```

I already created the `Map` between `UserEntity` and `UserDto` but obviously I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to create the mapping between `PagedListResult<UserEntity>` and  `PagedListResult<UserDto>`, then this test passes:

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<UserEntity, UserDto>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<PagedListResult<UserEntity>, PagedListResult<UserDto>>();
}

[Test]
public void Q33128288()
{
    PagedListResult<UserEntity> result = new PagedListResult<UserEntity>
    {
        Records = new List<UserEntity> {new UserEntity {Id = 7}},
        RecordCount = 1
    };

    var pagedListOfDtos = Mapper.Map<PagedListResult<UserDto>>(result);

    Assert.AreEqual(1, pagedListOfDtos.RecordCount);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, pagedListOfDtos.Records.Count());
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(UserDto), pagedListOfDtos.Records.Single());
    Assert.AreEqual(7, pagedListOfDtos.Records.Single().Id);
}
```

Comment: i am getting exception ..can u pls check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56723360/automapper-map-class-with-generic-list

Comment: I know it's been a long time since the question and the answer were made but I'm currently facing the same dilemma. And even though the solution it make sense, it's not practical at least on my context.
The idea of using a  **generic** "PagedListResult<T>" is to be able to pass any possible domain object, similar to what we do with List<T>. So, if I have to create a mapping for every single T replacement I may need I don't think it would be really useful ... at least on my scenario.

Comment: @SebastianInones does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380976/automapper-generic-mapping

Comment: Thanks for the link but unfortunately, I'm not looking to map the PagedList into a PagelistDTO for instance, rather what you mentioned in you answer  in a more reusable way.
For instance: 
 CreateMap<PagedResponse<IEnumerable<Tareasinformatica>>, PagedResponse<IEnumerable<TareasinformaticaDTO>>>();
And then, be able to reuse it with different domain objects.
Maybe I'm watching the problem from the wrong angle.