# Generic class of one type to another type in auto mapper

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-core, automapper

I have this Generic Pagination class: i want to map `PagedList<Caste> to PagedList<CasteModel>`

```
  public class PagedList<T>
        {
            public PagedList()
            {
            }
            public PagedList(IList<T> source, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
            {
                this.TotalItems = source.Count;
                this.PageNumber = pageNumber;
                this.PageSize = pageSize;
                this.Items = source;
            }

            public int TotalItems { get; set; }
            public int PageNumber { get; set; }
            public int PageSize { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }
            public int TotalPages => (int)Math.Ceiling(this.TotalItems / (double)this.PageSize);


        }
```

And Model  and View Model Classes

```
    public class Caste
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CasteCode { get; set; }
        public string CasteDesc { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public int? CasteParentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Caste CasteParent { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Caste> CasteChildren { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    }

public class CasteModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CasteCode { get; set; }
        public string CasteDesc { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public int? CasteParentId { get; set; }

    }
```

and below is my auto mapper configuration

```
 public class AppProfile : Profile
    {
        public AppProfile()
        {

            //Masters
            CreateMap<CasteModel, Caste>();
            CreateMap<Caste, CasteModel>();

            CreateMap(typeof(PagedList<>), typeof(PagedList<>));
         // CreateMap<PagedList<Caste>, PagedList<CasteModel>>(); ---This also checked
        }
```

This is the code for mapping in controller

```
 PagedList<Caste> result = new PagedList<Caste>
                {
                     Items = new List<Caste> { new Caste { Id = 7, CasteCode="" } },
                     TotalItems = 1
                };

                var pagedListOfDtos = Mapper.Map<PagedList<CasteModel>>(result);
```

When executing below error am getting below exception

"Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate configuration. If you are trying to use mapper instances through a container or otherwise, make sure you do not have any calls to the static Mapper.Map methods, and if you're using ProjectTo or UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you pass in the appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance."

Am using Asp.net core and automapper 6.1. Code is written based on below link
[generic list to automapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128288/automapper-map-class-with-generic-list-to-same-class-with-a-different-generic)
Please suggest a me solution tried a lot all getting same message

Comment: Mapper is static class, try Mapper.CreateMap<PagingModel, PagingParams>();

Comment: pagingModel is diffrent model.. now i have removed.. i have tried CreateMap<PagedList<Caste>, PagedList<CasteModel>>(); ..but same issue

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Comment: issue only  in Generic class mapping i.e PagedList<Caste> to PagedList<CasteModel>  .. Is it possible to map generic class of one type to another? or is there any other solution?

Comment: You don’t seem to be initialising AutoMapper, which would be why you’re getting that error: you have a profile, but you have to tell AutoMapper to use it!

Comment: Thank you very much @stuartd...I will check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Mapper.Map<PagedList<CasteModel>>(result);`, you need to initialize `Mapper` like below in `Startup.cs`

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<AppProfile>();
        });
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }
```

But, it it recommended to use `Dependence Injection` to resolve `Mapper`.

1. Install Package `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection`
2. `Startup.cs`

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
       services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
   }
   ```
3. UseCase

   ```
   public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
   {
       private readonly IMapper _mapper;
       public ValuesController(IMapper mapper)
       {
           _mapper = mapper;
       }
       // GET api/values
       [HttpGet]
       public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
       {
           PagedList<Caste> result = new PagedList<Caste>
           {
               Items = new List<Caste> { new Caste { Id = 7, CasteCode = "" } },
               TotalItems = 1
           };

           var pagedListOfDtos = _mapper.Map<PagedList<CasteModel>>(result);
           return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
       }       
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks its working now...but Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<AppProfile>();
        });   showing obsolete ..is there any solution?

Comment: @Ljt Try the first option with Dependence Inection.

Comment: yes.. am doing first option with Dependence Injection..But its working now ..but it shows obsolete in startup class for initialize..any way thanks for reply

Comment: @Ljt It's my mistake, try the second option with `services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));`

Comment: if i use only services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));in the start up class i am getting same error in the question only for generic class model.for other class model it works fine..may be the automapper issue

Comment: @Ljt Are you using `IMapper` or `Mapper`?

Comment: @Ljt You may consider creating a new thread with your current implementation.