# How to pass dynamic source to Mapper.CreateMap<source, destination> method in automapper

Tags: automapper

I have a scenario that i have to pass source class as dynamic. I tried it with generic type class but its not working.

```
public virtual void MapAttributeFact<T>()
{ 
  Mapper.CreateMap<T, DTO.TabRender.Attribute>()
 .ForMember(dest => dest.IsMultiSelect, src => src.MapFrom(opt => opt.MultiSelect))
}
```

Please help me how to pass it as dynamic.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to define what is the type of T in Createamap , check this link ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380976/automapper-generic-mapping

Comment: This is [documented in Dynamic and ExpandoObject Mapping](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping) but requires [AutoMapper 4.2 or later](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/01/28/automapper-4-2-0-released/)